# "In this regard" vs "in regards to this"

Tags: grammaticality, formality

I am not a native English speaker but have had English as the medium of instruction throughout my education. While writing an email application, I wrote this line as a concluding statement.

> "Let me know if there are any opportunities in this regard".

However, I am now confused as to whether I should have written

> "Let me know if there are any opportunities in regards to this."

What is the correct way of expressing this sentiment, and if both are grammatically correct, which one is preferred in a formal context like an email?

Comment: ***In this/that regard:***  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20that%2Fthis%20regard

Comment: ***In/with regard to:*** https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/in-with-regard-to